# Google's Refresh Access token Api not working from SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I was trying to build a small application which uses the some basic google calendar apis. Since the access token generated expires after every 60 minutes, I wanted to automatically call the refresh access token api and replace the old access token with the new one.

To do that I am calling the below api :

```
POST /o/oauth2/token?client_id={clientId}
&client_secret={secret}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&access_type=offline
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar
&refresh_token={refreshToken} HTTP/1.1

Host: accounts.google.com
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4a8e2563-4e31-431d-9e19-a442fb419590,1f750768-a6f5-42de-9f52-05555ac79c01
Host: accounts.google.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

I tried calling this api from postman and **it is working totally fine**, but when I try the same through Spring boot I am getting 400 Bad Request error. Below is the code that I've used to test different scenarios.

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Accept", "*/*");
    requestHeaders.add("Host", "accounts.google.com");
    //requestHeaders.add("User-Agent", "HTTPie/0.6.0");
    requestHeaders.add("Accept-Encoding", "*/*");
    requestHeaders.add("Content-Type",  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
    String REFRESH_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?"+
        "client_id={exact same client id}" +
        "&client_secret={exact same client secret}" +
        "&grant_type=refresh_token" +
        "&access_type=offline" +
        "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar" +
        "&refresh_token={exact same refresh token}";
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(REFRESH_TOKEN_URL, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Object.class);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.
Please help me out on this ( I am already stuck for more than 1 day ).

P.S : I might have to integrate this code in my company's product and the google client sdk can't be used. That's why I was trying to explore the api option.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you are trying to do. You can use the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/), it will help you to set up the accessToken and refreshToken and be able to handle them more easily.

Check this code I took from the [Java Calendar Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) (with some little modifications), which help you to call the Google Calendar API:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws Exception {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = Calendar.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // System.out.println(clientSecrets.getDetails());
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credentials = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);


        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        Events events = service.events().list("primary").execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No events found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("events found.");
            for(Event event: items){
                System.out.println(event.getSummary());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

These are the Maven dependencies I used just in case you prefer Maven, instead of Graddle as it appears in the quickstart:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-admin-directory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-admin-directory</artifactId>
            <version>directory_v1-rev110-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-calendar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev379-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-beans</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

### Notice

Remember to put the ***credentials.json*** file in your ***resources*** folder.

Comment: Actually the code that I am trying to run might be used in my company's micro service and I think they wouldn't allow the usage of the client library. So that's why I was trying to look out the api route.